# How access the nested json data using ng-repeat or angular.forEach

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

i have the following json file. i am unable to get the data dynamically. please help me to solve this issue.
my requirement is i need to view the url value based on the submodule ie; sname || id. if i am accessing the sname as chapter1 i need to get all the vid -> url values that are present for that sub module.

```js
[
   {
      "name":"Introduction - About The PMP Credential",
      "sub1":[
         {
            "sname":"Introduction to PMP",
            "id":"1",
            "vid":[
               {
                  "url":"www.abcd.co"
               },
               {
                  "url":"www.xyz.com"
               },
               {
                  "url":"www.xyz.com"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "sname":"Chapter1",
            "id":"2",
            "vid":[
               {
                  "url":"www.abcd.co"
               },
               {
                  "url":"www.xyz.com"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "sname":"Justification",
            "id":"3",
            "vid":[
               {
                  "url":"www.abcd.co"
               },
               {
                  "url":"www.xyz.com"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "name":"Project Management Framework",
      "sub1":[
         {
            "sname":"Project Seminar",
            "id":"4",
            "vid":[
               {
                  "url":"www.abcd.co"
               },
               {
                  "url":"www.xyz.com"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "sname":"Introduction to Communication Management",
            "id":"5",
            "vid":[
               {
                  "url":"www.abcd.co"
               },
               {
                  "url":"www.xyz.com"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "sname":"Final Communication Management",
            "id":"6",
            "vid":[
               {
                  "url":"www.abcd.co"
               },
               {
                  "url":"www.xyz.com"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "sname":"Modules",
            "id":"7",
            "vid":[
               {
                  "url":"www.abcd.co"
               },
               {
                  "url":"www.xyz.com"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "name":"Cost Management",
      "sub1":[
         {
            "sname":"Introduction to Cost Management",
            "id":"8",
            "vid":[
               {
                  "url":"www.abcd.co"
               },
               {
                  "url":"www.xyz.com"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "sname":"Cost Management Introduction",
            "id":"9",
            "vid":[
               {
                  "url":"www.abcd.co"
               },
               {
                  "url":"www.xyz.com"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: You should show what have you already tried ...

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div ng-repeat="item_nm in test">{{item_nm.name}}
        <div ng-repeat="sub1_dt in item_nm.sub1">
            {{sub1_dt.sname}}
            <div ng-repeat="vid in sub1_dt.vid">
                {{vid.url}}
            </div> 
      </div> 
    </div>

This will display name and corresponding sname and its url.
```